# Java - Spring - portlet API @Controller how to read ajax parameters

Tags: java, spring, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I have following latest jquery v aajx call with multiple parameters.

In java code i am able to get only first parameter value rest of them found null.

```
$.ajax({
        url : '<portlet:resourceURL id="entitledRequest"/>',
        data: '<c:out value="pfx= ${account.accountNumber}-${outletUI.outlet}-${count}&acc=${account.accountNumber}" />',
        cache: false,
        success : function(result) {

            //targetElem.html(result); update uI

        }
    });
```

Following is my java code only first parameter is not null after that all params are null, i have debug http request all parameters are present in the request object any clue whats wrong here ?

```
Controller("ajaxRequestController")
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
public class AjaxRequestController implements PortletConfigAware  {


@ResourceMapping("entitledRequest")
    public void getServiceAutoComplete(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) throws IOException {


            String elemPrefix = request.getParameter("pfx");
            String acc = request.getParameter("acc"); // found null
            String mac = request.getParameter("mac"); // found null

}...
```

Comment: What's the value of `elemPrefix`? Does it contain the full `c:out` or just the `pfx` parameter? Doesn't look like you have a `mac` paramter.

Comment: there is only one c:out for all params as you can see in the question  and created one string for request param.

Comment: What is the string value that `request.getParameter("pfx");` returns, exactly?

Comment: it is uniqe number some thing like 456565-44-1

Comment: Try to set the values as `var`s in javascript and pass them to `data` as `key:value` pairs.

Comment: i tried this and now every thing is null '{<c:out value="pfx: ${account.accountNumber}_${outletUI.outlet}_${count}, acc:${account.accountNumber}" />}'

Comment: You misunderstood what I meant. Before the `ajax()` call, set some javascript variables, like `var pfx = '<c:out value="${yourthing}" />';`. Then, in `data`, `data : {"pfx" : pfx, "acc" :acc ...}`. Jquery will make sure to append them as URL parameters in the GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@RequestParam` annotation to read the Parameters.

```
@ResourceMapping("entitledRequest")
public void getServiceAutoComplete(@RequestParam("pfx")  String elemPrefix, @RequestParam  String acc, @RequestParam String mac, ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) throws IOException {

}
```

## Reason:

The `Parameters` sent by `Ajax` doesn't fall in the `PortletNamespace`. Hence, they are not part of the `ResourceRequest` but they can be found in normal `HTTPServletRequest`. `Spring` searches the `@RequestParam` names in `HTTPServletRequest`.

You can either use the approach suggested by me -or- you can add the `<portlet:namespace/>` to your parameters in the `Ajax` call keeping your `Controller` code intact.

Comment: Rite now i am revert back from ajax call, but for next feature i have to work on ajax then i will be able to test this, i will update my response.

Comment: @Faisalkhan Thanks, you have followed up this post. Please do accept it if that works.

Comment: $.get("test.cgi", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
.done(function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});